# Powerline-Status bar real-time update and fixed

Tags: linux, zsh, oh-my-zsh, powerline

I found this amazing plugin for zsh called powerline-status, through the screenshots from oh-my-zsh:
[Screenshot](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/2618447/6316861/70f3c4ce-ba03-11e4-88a5-0b423dd5a2ce.png)

Now i dont know if thats photoshop, but I didnt find a way to get the stats fixed on the bottom side of the console, like in the screenshot. I assume they are updated in real time as well.
I got powerline up and running as a prompt with left and right site segments, though.

Does anybody know, how to achieve the same result, like in the screenshot?
Thanks in advance!

BTW my OS is elementary OS Freya.

Comment: That bottom status line looks like the `tmux` status line, or from the terminal emulator (but I've yet to know a terminal emulator with customizable tab bar). Definitely impossible from within the shell. (Just use common sense: how can your shell know about other processes: 1. `irssi`, 2. `zsh`, blah blah...?)

Comment: By the way, here's a screenshot hosted on Wikimedia showing that your screenshot is indeed from tmux (with powerline): https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tmux-powerline.png.